# WindowsApps folder says permissions are corrupted and need to be deleted, is this normal or critical?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, gaming, windows-store-app

[image: Here is the error]

This is for principle: Users, other principles dont show this message.

After being unable to launch Forza without it crashing, and did everything suggested but nothing worked, I went to WindowsApps folder, right click to permissions and discovered this warning.

Comment: NEVER change user permission of Windows apps folder. Bad things happened who tried that. Contact the game developer in Windows Store.

Comment: The game dev wont help. All apps work except one, Forza 7. Its been suggested to change permissions, but i saw this corruption warning and thought it may need fixing.

Comment: Your post is unclear. Right-click has Properties but not Permissions. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Running into the same issue. Tried to uninstall Forza Motorsport 6: Apex to realize it did not uninstall. All 21.8 GB of files are still on my system, under this folder. I've wondered if it is an access issue. Only, I cannot access the folder and I am getting this error message too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is unfortunately normal.  Amazingly, the `WindowsApps` folder(s) don't follow the normal ACL rules.  This is a very strong reason to completely avoid all Windows Store apps whenever possible.

[Edit] I'm not sure why the downvote, this answer is correct.  You can easily check it on your own system, by right-clicking C:\Program files\WindowsApp --> Properties --> Security --> Advanced --> Edit

Comment: I don't think so. This problem arises easily if 1) the ownership of `WindowsApps` is changed, 2) its children's ownership isn't changed and 3) the process of recursively allowing admins to access `WindowsApps` and its children is canceled (after an error message).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you try the following steps:

1. Navigate to the location C:\Program Files.
2. Right-click on the WindowsApps folder, and select Properties.
3. Turn to Security tab and click on Advanced.
4. Click on Change and then type Users in Enter the object name to select area.
5. Click on OK, then click Apply > OK. You can also add the TrustedInstaller to the users list and check if it takes effect.

However, you might be still not able to access the files. The workaround is to go inside the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\, and repeat the same way with the Microsoft.WindowsStore* folders.

Comment: I have seen this listed as the proper solution many times, only I do not have TrustedInstaller as an available user or group or anything.

Comment: Setting this to administrators or administrator did not work, but setting it to my default account (my email address) did work. Seems insecure though.